# Angular2 RC2 Select Option selectedIndex

Tags: typescript, angular

I got a non-unique select options like this, same value mean different thing. Our data is like that and I can only work to fit the data.

```html
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value = "1">Apple</option>
  <option value = "2">Orange</option>
  <option value = "3">Pineapple</option>
  <option value = "1">Banana</option>
</select>
```

So I can set value by setting selectedIndex.

```
document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex = 3;
```

But in Angular 2, I got error on this statement "Property 'selectedIndex' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'. any".

How can I find selectedIndex with Angular2 or how can I get around it?

Update:
I am trying to **set default value** to the select option according to other data retrieved from the database. So it' something like

```
this.data$.subscribe(data => {
    this.data = data; 
    if (data.someConditionMet) { 
      document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex = 3;
    }
}, 
error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
```

Please note that the values in the options could be duplicate. But the entries are not. value "1" could represent either "Apple" or "Banana". That's why I want to use index rather than value.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. Please read carefully. It's about setting default value to non-unique options.

Comment: You need to cast the document.getElementById("mySelect") to class HTMLSelectElement before trying to use the selectedIndex property:

(<HTMLSelectElement>document.getElementById("mySelect")).selectedIndex = 3;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically, you would take a different approach in Angular 2. You would have your data control the dom, not the other way around.

Something like this:

```
<select id="mySelect">
  <option *ngFor="let dataValue of myDataArray" value = "dataValue.value" (click)="onSelected(dataValue)">{{dataValue.Text}}</option>
</select>
```

And then have a handler `onSelected` in your component, which knows which data item was selected.

You want a default selection based on your data?
Just add `[selected]="someJavascriptExpression"` to the `option` element.
Eg: `[selected]="dataValue.value === someCond && dataValue.text === someOtherCond"`. Whatever makes each `option` element unique based on your data.

Comment: hholtij, I did that already. I am trying to set default value when data is retrieved from database. I just updated my question. So any further input? Appreciate it.

Comment: Just add [selected]="dataValue.value === someCondition" to the option element.

Comment: value 1 could represent either "Apple" or "Banana". That's why I want to use index rather than value.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the model of the select to set or get the current value:

```html
<select id="mySelect" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
  <option *ngFor="let dataValue of myDataArray" 
           value="dataValue.value" 
           (click)="onSelected(dataValue)">
    {{dataValue.Text}}
  </option>
</select>
```

In your component:

```
export class ComponentA {
    selectedValue: number = -1;

    // ...

    this.data$.subscribe(data => {
            this.data = data; 
            if (data.someConditionMet) { 
                selectedValue = 3;
            }
        }, 
        error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error
    );
```

Comment: I had that, Please note that the the values in the option list is non-unique. So using [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" may end up undesired result.

Comment: What is this select for anyway if it has duplicate entries? Go with @hholtij's comment then ...

Comment: Something about an entry must be unique, otherwise the selection would be meaningless. If it's not the value then maybe a combination of value and text. You can basically have any javascript expression in the [selected] attribute, eg [selected]="dataValue.value === someCond && dataValue.text === someOtherCond"

Answer (score 2):

Use $event.target.selectedIndex. let selIdx = 0. Then,

```
<select (change)="selIdx = $event.target.selectedIndex;"> Select One
   <option *ngFor="let a of array;let i = index;" value="{{ a.val }}"  [selected]="selIdx == i">
      {{ a.desc }}
   </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just found something interesting.

For non-unique select options, Angular2 transforms the values, adding an index automatically. For example, from

```
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value = "1">Apple</option>
  <option value = "2">Orange</option>
  <option value = "3">Pineapple</option>
  <option value = "1">Banana</option>
</select>
```

to

```
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value = "0: 1">Apple</option>
  <option value = "1: 2">Orange</option>
  <option value = "2: 3">Pineapple</option>
  <option value = "3: 1">Banana</option>
</select>
```

So in my code, I can just do

```
this.data$.subscribe(data => {
    this.data = data; 
    if (data.someConditionMetForBanana) { 
      ngModelBoundSelectedValue = "3: 1";
    }
}, 
error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
```

hholtij was correct in his comment. And Angular2 does this wonderful thing for us.