# Get select-selectedIndex and click event under select-option in Angular4

Tags: angular, html-select

I want get selectedIndex and then get the select data model, then I found I could directly get the selected data model [Angular2 RC2 Select Option selectedIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38235055/angular2-rc2-select-option-selectedindex). However, click event under option doesn't work.

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker" #Code name="Code" [(ngModel)]="model.Code">
    <option value="" selected="selected">--Please select--</option>
    <option *ngFor="let x of Codes" [value]="x.Code" [selected]="x.Code == model.Code" (click)="searchWithCode(x)">{{x.Name}}</option>
</select>`

searchWithCode(code:any) : void {
    this.model.Name1 = code.Name1;
    this.model.Name2 = code.Name2;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use change event in dropdown :

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker" #Code name="Code" [(ngModel)]="model.Code" (change)="searchWithCode($event)">
    <option value="" selected="selected">--Please select--</option>
    <option *ngFor="let x of Codes" [value]="x.Code" [selected]="x.Code == model.Code" >{{x.Name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: how could I get the selectedIndex or selected option data from event?

Comment: You can pass model in change event so you can get in .ts file

Comment: I mean I  used (change)="function($event)" first, but I don't konw how to get   selectedIndex or selected option data from event, so I give this method up.

Comment: Try this (change)="searchWithCode($event,model)"

Comment: Thanks very much, I think I'd better speak out what I want to do. then you can help me easily. I how many readonly fields to fill from select data-source, when I select one option, I want to get model data from selected option(that is to say: x under *ngFor). so have to get the selectedIndex in select or the option model data(x under *ngFor)), (change)="searchWithCode($event,model)" can't give me a flag of selected data, so I don't think this will work.

Comment: I figured it out from console in devtools: event.target.selectedIndex, I have got idea from taliking with you, Thanks!!!

Comment: @KevinXiong great keep it up

Comment: Would like to give more infomation when someone who has the same problem and not proficient in javascript like me. use **event.target["selectedIndex"]** instead of event.target.selectedIndex as event.target.selectedIndex just work in runtime, as I had add "Please select" ahead, so you have to use event.target["selectedIndex"] - 1 to get the selectedIndex of select.